# Error when trying to export android project to apk

Tags: android, package, apk, signed

I cannot resolve this problem and I am here for help. When I try to export my android project to apk in eclipse (any way - by exporting signed or unsigned application project) I'm receiving an error -

```
"Failed to export application Command-line Error -1073741816 ".
```

I have all the tools provided from google (SDK, ADT etc. from this one package - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ). I read here that this is a java 7 problem - so, I reinstalled it to java 6, changed settings in eclipse preferences and this doesn't helped. Another step was installing eclipse from eclipse website, and separately SDK from google and ADT. Doesn't help.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever run the code on an emulator or deivce?

Comment: Also right now I downloaded entire new SDK from google and installed newest Java7. Then I created new project in new workspace, just simple hello world. When I run it on phone there is no problem, when I try to export it, BOOM CRASH! Of course with this problem.

Comment: Do you need only the unsigned apk?

Comment: No matter if I try to export it to signed or unsigned app, the same problem :/ Even I deleted EVERYTHING (java, eclipse), installed from beginning, java 7 and android SDK from google, created hello world app and this problem occurs when I try to exprot app (unsigned and signed). :/ When I test it on the phone or AVD, no problems!

Comment: But it would be better if I was able to create a signed apk.

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse, go to Project -> Build Automatically and uncheck it. Then, try to export again using the Android Tools.

Comment: Nope, unfortunetly it didn't help. Also I found that changing "Preferences/Android/Build" to verbose could help, but didn't. In problems-> description i have the "Error executing aapt - return code 1073741816" that appears only when I try to export my app. Funny thing is that I can without problem test my app on my phone, and in that process eclipse is creating an apk on the phone and then executing it, but when I try only exporting apk, it gives me this error. So annoying.

Comment: @AdamSt you found a solution ?

Comment: Well, if You can call installing a Virtual Machine Windows XP and there eclipse, then yes, I found it :D Otherwise, not. It was simplier than this whole reinstalling of java, looking for an error in preferences, of course without any result...