# Android Eclipse after taken signed build, when try to install getting error for while parsing the package

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, eclipse-juno

I am using Android Juno 64 bit Eclipse, 64 bit jdk, 64 bit os windows.
I am tried to take Signed build in eclipse,Its could not take full mb apk file.
Actually while running application, get apk from bin folder, Its for 5.5 mb exact size.
while tried to install the signed build in my mobile, getting package parsing error.
Anyone help to sort out this issue.
Already I refered this link also.
[Error when trying to export android project to apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200238/error-when-trying-to-export-android-project-to-apk#)
["Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package" while installing Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android)

Comment: I really suggest you move on to Android Studio. I was also cautious first, I finally changed last fall, and I never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

The error is displayed when your `apk` is build with the minimum `sdk` higher than your device in which you are trying to install. Kindly check the minimum `sdk` of your project.

Google has ended support for eclipse so it will better for you to move on `Android Studio`.